# Command added to rc.local has no effect

Tags: boot

In some post here, I read that if I wanted to run a shell script at start up, I would have to add it at the end of /etc/rc.local but before exit 0. However, when I do this it seems to have no effect. Specifically, I am using my Pi3 as a Access Point and for some reason, I always have to `sudo service hostapd restart` after boot to make it work. Adding this line to /etc/rc.local does not have the same effect. Where can I add this line so it really only executes after everything else has loaded?

Here are the contents of /etc/rc.local

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

# Print the IP address
_IP=$(hostname -I) || true
if [ "$_IP" ]; then
  printf "My IP address is %s\n" "$_IP"
fi

sudo service hostapd restart

exit 0
```

Comment: post the content of the rc.local file to show if there is something wrong there

Answer (score 3):

If those articles you're using predate systemd, be aware that `rc.local` compatibility is provided via a `systemd` service. On a fresh install, you will see a "Start /etc/rc.local Compatability" boot message if you're running newer versions of raspbian.

After modifying `/etc/rc.local`, check the status of the service with `sudo systemctl status rc-local`. You may see a warning that your must run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`.

Depending on what you run in `/etc/rc.local`, the startup order may not be correct. In this case, if you need to ensure the order of startup (e.g. hostapd only after networking is fully up), then creating a proper `systemd` service will be required.

Note that some of this may vary depending on whether you upgraded to stretch or did a fresh install, or on what else you've installed.

[This article on U&L SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332938/rc-local-not-working-debian-8) may be useful for replacing `/etc/rc.local` with a `systemd` equivalent. There is a [good discussion](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=122207) on the RPi forums noting that it is executed, but early in the boot process, likely before networking is available.

In short, you want to create and enable a `systemd` service file to launch things in the proper sequence during boot.

Comment: I don't quite understand the discussions in the links you provided. I feel like there should be a simple way of running a command at startup after everything else has loaded. It shouldn't be more complicated than adding a line somewhere. What am I missing?

Comment: In short: /etc/rc.local and @reboot in crontab still exist, but their ordering can be a problem with the new systemd scheme. Work-arounds exist (e.g. https://packages.debian.org/stretch/systemd-cron - not installed by default), but may take some work. In your case, try doing `sudo systemctl status rc-local` to see if there are any errors. If you modified rc.local, you may have to re-enable it. Will edit answer to clarify.

Comment: sorry, I fail to see why you are saying this: "After modifying /etc/rc.local, check the status of the service with sudo systemctl status rc-local. You may see a warning that your must run sudo systemctl daemon-reload." So yes, there is a warning. But how do I perform this reload and why would that fix my problem with rc.local?

Comment: Because it's a significant change from the previous behavior of /etc/rc.local that can easily be overlooked. Changes to /etc/rc.local without checking the status will silently fail otherwise, and the startup message may be missed. The OP made such a modification.

Comment: but how does this help me to solve the problem? I need to know where I have to add my line sudo service hostapd restart so that it executes after everyting else during bootup. I am no expert in any of this, but I imagine during boot a series of scripts is executed which are stored in some files. Hence, I would like to pinpoint the file which is used last in this process. This would be the file I have to add the code to, or is this incorrect?

Comment: You could try leaving it as you have it (removing the sudo), and making sure `/etc/rc.local` is actually being executed with `sudo systemctl status rc-local`. It will likely give you the message that you need to run `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`. If that works, you're done. If you need to guarantee it loads later -- say after a 30 second timeout -- you may have to get familiar with `systemd` service files and configuration. I'm assuming you're running a version of raspbian using `systemd`. Please provide the details on your OS.

Comment: Ok, so I executed "sudo systemctl status rc-local". This gives the warning. Then I type "sudo systemctl daemon-reload" and then "sudo systemctl status rc-local" again. Now the warning is gone. However when I reboot, rc.local has not been executed and "sudo systemctl status rc-local" shows the warning again. I am using the latest version of Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: Does the status message indicate "active (exited)" which indicates it ran? Do you see the IP address message on startup? (We're getting into an extended discussion which is frowned upon. You should probably edit your question to include more detail.)

Answer (score 1):

Check out the line that says:

```
sudo nano service hostapd restart
```

It's opening nano, it should be:

```
sudo service hostapd restart
```

Edit:

From [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/rc-local.md):

> If your command runs continuously (perhaps runs an infinite loop) or is likely not to exit, you must be sure to fork the process by adding an ampersand to the end of the command, like so:

I don't think that it's your problem, but try it, maybe it will work:

```
sudo service hostapd restart &
```

Comment: sorry, it's actually correct in my file. I don't know why I added it above. Edited.

Comment: I've edited my answer, but I'm 99% sure that it's not going to work :(

Comment: Do not use `sudo` in `/etc/rc.local`, it is run with root privileges by the init system.  If you need to test it otherwise, use `sudo /etc/rc.local`.

Comment: forking does not work. Also it makes no difference not to use sudo, still does not work. I also tried without sudo and fork, no luck.